# How to express F(x) in terms of G(x)?

Tags: definite-integrals

How to express $$F(x)=\int _{ 1 }^{ x }{ \frac { e^{ t } }{ t^2 }  dt} $$ in terms of  $$ G(x)=\int _{ 1 }^{ x }{ \frac { e^{ t } }{ t }  dt} $$ ?

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, taking $u=-\frac{1}{t}$ (and so $u'=\frac{1}{t^2}$), $v=e^t$ and using the integration by parts formula $(\int u'v=[uv]-\int uv')$ that : $$F(x)=\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t^2}dt=\Big[-\frac{e^t}{t}\Big]_1^x+\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t}dt,$$  and so
$$F(x)=e-\frac{e^x}{x}+G(x).$$

Comment: I didnt get the fist step.What is your first function and what is your second function during by parts?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta : I edited that !

Comment: @Baloown This is wrong.

Comment: @RPH : Yes I edited that by the way too, thank you !

Comment: @Baloown ok..(y)

Answer (score 0):

Use integration by parts

$$F(x)=\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t^2}dt=\int_1^xe^t\cdot(-1)(\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{t}))dt=(\frac{-e^t}{t})_1^x+\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t}dt=\frac{-e^x}{x}+e+G(x)$$

$$F(x)=G(x)+e-\frac{e^x}{x}$$